# OAuth2 "client credentials" grant: remote IP check?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm developing an API which only needs to be accessed by servers, as opposed to specific, human users. I've been using the *client credentials* grant which, if I'm not mistaken, is appropriate for this use case.

So the remote websites/apps, after registering their corresponding OAuth2 clients, are simply requesting an an access token using their client ID/secret combination, via a SSL POST request + HTTP Basic authentication.

**Now I was wondering if it would be a good idea, during said access token request, to check the remote IP to make sure it actually belongs to the client that was registered (you'd have to state one or several IPs when declaring your app, then it would be checked against the remote IP of the server making the POST /token request).**

I feel like this would be an easy way to make sure that, even if the client ID/secret are somehow stolen, they wouldn't be just usable from anywhere.

Being fairly new to the OAuth2 protocol, I need some input as to whether this is a valid approach. Is there a more clever way to do this, or is it straight up unnecessary (in which case, for what reasons)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! What did you decide to use finally? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's certainly a valid approach but binds the token tightly to the network layer and deployment which may make it difficult to change the network architecture. The way that OAuth addresses your concern is by the so-called Proof-of-Possession extensions https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-pop-architecture.

It may be worth considering implementing that: even though it is not a finalized specification yet, it binds the token to the client instead of the IP address which safeguards against network changes and is more future proof.

Comment: Very interesting--and indeed, looks like the right OAuth-way of addressing it. Not sure I'll try and implement this right away (might be a little bit time-intensive), but at least I know what to aim for. Thanks!

Comment: FYI This draft expired January 9, 2017 .  This may now be more relevant: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tokbind-protocol-15

Comment: Updated again :) https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-dpop, or a nicer home: https://oauth.net/2/dpop